# Ngrx dispatch one action multiple times at once

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

My app has 3 download buttons
Each button click will dispatch **DownloadFileAction(payload=fileId)**
An Effect will keep listening for Download_File_Action type

```
@effect()
download_attachment$: Observable = this.actions$
.ofType(FileActions.ActionTypes.DOWNLOAD_ATTACHMENT)
.map(toPayload)
.switchMap( attachment => {
return this.service.downloadAttachment(attachment.link) //absolute link
.map( (data) => {
this.service.saveAttachment(data); //save file locally
return new FileActions.DownloadAttachmentSuccessAction(attachment);
})
.catch(error => {
//debugger;
console.log(error);
});
```

})

If more than 1 button are clicked at the same time, 2 DownloadFileAction actions will be dispatched

Howerver, download_attachment$ effect only listen for one which is downloaded first and then return DownloadAttachmentSuccessAction, thus the other downloading files will not be finished

Is there any solution or workaround ?
Your idea is much appreciated

Comment: Replace `switchMap` with `mergeMap`.

Comment: Thanks @cartant, mergeMap works perfectly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @cartant mentioned in a comment, replace `switchMap` with `mergeMap`.

The difference being, `switchMap` will *switch* contexts everytime the parent observable fires and `mergeMap` will keep listening to the parent observable and *merge* or combine the results.

### SwitchMap

In essence the `switchMap` is unsubscribing from the parent observable's first stream when the parent observable emits a new value.

[image]

In the marble diagram, you can see when `3` is emitted and then `5` is emitted, the final output doesn't include 3 `30`s because when `5` was emitted, it *switched* contexts and the values are dropped.

### MergeMap

MergeMap will merge all the values emitted from the parent observable.

[image]

In the marble diagram for `mergeMap` you can see all values get emitted for every value emitted from the parent observable.  ie, all `30`s get emitted, even though the last value comes in after `5` is emitted from the parent.

Hope that helps illustrate it a little better.

Comment: Thanks @TylerJenning for your answer and clear explanation.